# SQL: placement of inner joins and impact of performance and correctness

Tags: sql

Is there any difference ( in performance and correctness) between these to SQL (sqls are not important)

SQL no. 1

```
    SELECT a.test1,
           a.test2,
           a.test3,
           b.test1,
           b.test2,
           b.test3,
           c.test1,
           c.test2,
           c.test3
    FROM table_1 a
    JOIN table_2 b ON a.id = b.id
    AND (a.test1 ="test")
    AND (b.test2 = "test")
    JOIN table_3 c ON c.id2 = b.id2
```

SQL no. 2

```
SELECT a.test1,
       a.test2,
       a.test3,
       b.test1,
       b.test2,
       b.test3,
       c.test1,
       c.test2,
       c.test3
FROM table_3 c
JOIN table_2 b ON c.id2 = b.id2
JOIN table_1 a ON a.id = b.id
AND (a.test1 ="test")
AND (b.test2 = "test")
```

also, table a has 500 000 records, table b has 1000 000 and table c has 1 5000 00 records

Comment: Have a look an *query plan* - way how RDBMS executes the query

Comment: Trust the optimizer. Write SQL that is readable. (Which includes having a WHERE clause for filtering conditions.)

Comment: is it correct to say that in general there is no way to answer this question without optimizer / profiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I don't think reversing the join statements will make much of a difference. Either way the program will have to combine the data of the table with the data of the two other tables. The calculations that have to be performed don't seem to be affected by the joins. If the first join changed the length of the data that needed to be analysed to perform the second join, I could see why the query execution time would be affected, as would the results. But aren't the statements independent of eachother? Measuring time of queries can be done like following in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
set statistics time on

$query_to_be_measured

set statistics time off
```

Comment: SQL Server management Studio. I edited this in the post